# Why does this method work?

Tags: recursion, return-value, recursive-backtracking

This is a recursive backtracking method that finds whether or not a given array can sum to a target amount.
This works:

```
  public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if(start >= nums.length)
    return target ==0;
  if(!groupSum(start+1,nums,target-nums[start]))
    return groupSum(start+1,nums,target);
  return true;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
  public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if(start >= nums.length)
    return target ==0;
  if(!groupSum(start+1,nums,target-nums[start]))
    return groupSum(start+1,nums,target);
  return false;
}
```

How does the method even reach the final return statement?

Comment: Can you highlight the difference in the two programs? I've been looking for over a minute and I still don't see it...

Comment: It's the final return statement in both methods.

Comment: `How does the method even reach the final return statement?` - same way the first method does? It returns finally when the the stack is depleted - if it didn't you'd have a stackoverflow.

Comment: shouldn't the return target ==0 end the stack?

Comment: `!false` is equal to `true`, so in the second program, you will recur *both* `groupSum` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program you have two `if` statements that both ends up returning. If both of them are false, then the last return is in effect. Thus you can expect this to be true when you hit the last line of your function:

```java
start < nums.length && groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])
```

I think perhaps a little more clear version would be this:

```java
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if (start >= nums.length)
    return target == 0;
  if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]))
    return true;
  return groupSum(start + 1, nums, target);
}
```

It is exactly the same logic except I've switched the two last and reversed the predicate (removed the not).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I appreciate it.